# How to make single where condition for this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am using MSSQL 2005 Server and I have the following SQL query.

```
IF @CategoryId IN (1,2,3)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @search_temp_table 
        SELECT * FROM (SELECT d.DataId, (SELECT [Name] FROM Category WHERE CategoryId = d.CategoryId) AS 'Category', d.Description, d.CompanyName, d.City, d.CategoryId,
                d.CreatedOn, d.Rank, d.voteCount, d.commentCount, d.viewCount
        FROM Data d 
                INNER JOIN Keyword k
                    ON d.DataId = k.DataId
        WHERE FREETEXT(k.Keyword, @SearchQ) AND d.CategoryId=@CategoryId AND d.IsSearch=1 AND d.IsApproved=1 ) AS Search_Data
    END
    ELSE
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO @search_temp_table 
            SELECT * FROM (SELECT d.DataId, (SELECT [Name] FROM Category WHERE CategoryId = d.CategoryId) AS 'Category', d.Description, d.CompanyName, d.City, d.CategoryId,
                    d.CreatedOn, d.Rank, d.voteCount, d.commentCount, d.viewCount
            FROM Data d 
                    INNER JOIN Keyword k
                        ON d.DataId = k.DataId
            WHERE FREETEXT(k.Keyword, @SearchQ) AND d.IsSearch=1 AND d.IsApproved=1 ) AS Search_Data
        END
```

In the above query I have the category condition,

```
d.CategoryId=@CategoryId
```

which is executed when any category is passed, if no category is passed then I am not considering category condition in where clause, To implement category condition only when if the category in (1,2,3) I have used If-Clause, but can't we do this in single where query?? that means just check if the values is there in the category (or if it's easy then we can only check for 1,2,3 values) then that condition will be applied else query will not consider the category condition.

Is there any way, using CASE, or NOT NULL statements ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similiar to marks answer you can do the following:

```
WHERE FREETEXT(k.Keyword, @SearchQ) 
  AND d.IsSearch=1 
  AND d.IsApproved=1 
  AND ((@CategoryId NOT IN (1,2,3)) OR (d.CategoryId = @CategoryId))
) AS Search_Data
```

This way you eliminiate the function call

Answer (score 2):

If @CategoryId is NULL when you don't want to filter by it you can use the below condition...

```
ISNULL(@CategoryId, d.CategoryId) = d.CategoryId
```

So if it's NULL then it equals itself and wont filter

**EDIT**

I like Marc Miller's COALESCE example and you could use either and I really shouldn't comment on the performance of one verses the other but...

My gut tells me ISNULL should win out but have a [look](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/performance-isnull-vs-coalesce.aspx) at some of the debates on this issue if you have nothing better to do (or if performance is REALLY critical in this query).

**NOTE:** If the d.CategoryId in the table can be NULL then this approach will fail and the CASE WHEN THEN approach elsewhere on this question should be used

Comment: This doesn't check whether @Category is in 1,2 or 3.

Comment: Hmm - they way I read the question was that the values passed in could only be 1,2 or 3 and that was why they were in the IF statement. Either way it's a bloody good way of implementing optional filtering :)

Comment: This may also fail if the CategoryId in the table can be NULL

Comment: Good point - I've generally used this approach on IDENTITY columns so it's not been a problem for me in the past but I'll edit the post to point this out.

Answer (score 2):

If the only difference is your where clause then you could do this:

```
d.CategoryId = COALESCE(@CategoryId, d.CategoryId)
```

Not sure why you need the IN clause (IN (1,2,3)) as you mentioned that your reason for checking for it is to make sure it isn't NULL. So this should work the way you described.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a ((@CategoryId IN (1,2,3) AND CategoryId=@CategoryId) OR NOT @CategoryId IN (1,2,3)) will check category id if it is 1, 2 or 3 otherwise it won't apply that filter.

```
    WHERE FREETEXT(k.Keyword, @SearchQ) AND ((@CategoryId IN (1,2,3) AND d.CategoryId=@CategoryId) OR NOT @CategoryId IN (1,2,3))  AND d.IsSearch=1 AND d.IsApproved=1 ) AS Search_Data
```

Answer (score 1):

If category is in 1,2 or 3 then use the specified @CategoryId to filter or else don't by checking itself.

```
AND IsNull(d.CategoryId, 1) = case when @CategoryId in (1,2,3) then @CategoryId else IsNull(d.CategoryId, 1) end
```

This query also **works** when **@Category or CategoryId is null**
And the "If" statement can go away.

Full query below

```
INSERT INTO @search_temp_table 
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT d.DataId, (SELECT [Name] FROM Category WHERE CategoryId = d.CategoryId) AS 'Category', d.Description, d.CompanyName, d.City, d.CategoryId,
                    d.CreatedOn, d.Rank, d.voteCount, d.commentCount, d.viewCount
    FROM    Data d 
            INNER JOIN Keyword k ON d.DataId = k.DataId
    WHERE   FREETEXT(k.Keyword, @SearchQ) 
            AND IsNull(d.CategoryId, 1) = case when @CategoryId in (1,2,3) then @CategoryId else IsNull(d.CategoryId, 1) end
            AND d.IsSearch=1 
            AND d.IsApproved=1 ) AS Search_Data
```

***WARNING**: Make sure to check against execution plan whether above query is slower than using "if" statement.

Comment: This may not return the correct data if the CategoryId in the table can be NULL

Answer (score 1):

Could do a LEFT JOIN in there, like this:

```
INSERT INTO @search_temp_table
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  d.DataId,
            c.[Name] as 'Category',
            d.Description, d.CompanyName, d.City, d.CategoryId,
            d.CreatedOn, d.Rank, d.voteCount, d.commentCount, d.viewCount
            FROM Data d 
            INNER JOIN Keyword k ON d.DataId = k.DataId
            LEFT JOIN Category c on c.CategoryId=d.CategoryId
                AND c.CategoryId=@CategoryId
            WHERE FREETEXT(k.Keyword, @SearchQ)
            AND d.IsSearch=1
            AND d.IsApproved=1
) AS Search_Data
```

you wouldn't need the if statement anymore either.

Also, it's very important that you have the c.CategoryId=@CategoryId within the LEFT JOIN, if you move it to the WHERE clause it will force the LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN.